# Load testing a HTTP end-point from different geo-locations

Tags: http, load-testing

Is it possible to simulate a load test on a HTTP endpoint from different geo-locations. e.g. I want to simulate requests to http endpoint from US, Canada, Mexico, China...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll either need to employ a testing service for this (either full-service or self-service) or obtain your own computing resources to do this.  One of the cloud providers can give you the short-term resources you need a minimal cost. For example, Amazon EC2 has datacenters in 7 (8?) parts of the world. We use it in our testing services and it is integrated into our [load testing software](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) and it works great. The testing software you choose (and your site's performance requirements) will determine the kind and quantity of resources you'll need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested on having the actual requests coming from the different geo-locations or your interest is related to the latency associated with having requests coming form those locations?

If you real need is the second one, then you have a couple of options:

- Software based network emulation: E.g. [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997557.aspx#specifyingvirtualnetworktypesloadtestscenarios_truenetworkemulation) load testing allows you to simulate latency during load tests.
- Hardware based network emulation: solutions to simulate latency, also called WAN Emulators. E.g. SHUNRA

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that it's possible to specify [geographical location](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/42680-set-load-geographical-origin) in [Load Testing Cloud](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/42674-what-is-blazemeter-s-load-testing-cloud-) which is compatible with [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org). Use parameter 'Load Origin Location' when create load test.